# repeat a single row in all rows oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I repeat a value from one row to the others?
Here are the table and the desired result:

Normal table:

```
|SURVEY_ID  |    SONDA| DATA_CRIA   | ANSWER

CHK-SON-CS-07  PR-05    06/04/2022   1
CHK-SON-CS-07           06/04/2022   2
CHK-SON-CS-07           06/04/2022   3
CHK-SON-CS-07           06/04/2022   4
```

I need to repeat the PR-05 in all the rows.

Desired result

```
SURVEY_ID   |   SONDA | DATA_CRIA  | ANSWER
CHK-SON-CS-07   PR-05   06/04/2022  1
CHK-SON-CS-07   PR-05   06/04/2022  2
CHK-SON-CS-07   PR-05   06/04/2022  3
CHK-SON-CS-07   PR-05   06/04/2022  4
```

Comment: what if other rows contain value for SONDA column? if only one row contain value then how to find that row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest is something like this:

```
select survey_id, min(sonda) over () as sonda, data_cria, answer
from   <table_name>
;
```

The analytic function `min` returns the only non-null value from the column; as an analytic function (as opposed to its aggregate version), the value will be copied to each row of the input table.

More likely, you will want something like this where there are groups of rows (by `survey_id`, or perhaps by `survey_id` and `data_cria`), with one non-null `sonda` in each group, and you will want to do the same "copying" within each group (not over the entire table). If so, you can easily adapt the solution: instead of `over ()` you will use a partition clause, like `over(partition by survey_id)`, or `over (partition by survey_id, date_cria)`.

Comment: Hi, tks a lot all you guys for help.
I used the partition by with 3 criterias to not repeat the same sonda for others survey answers.

min(d.item_description) over (partition by c.emp_no,  trunc(c.DATE_CREATED), c.answer_set ) as sonda

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lag(ignore nulls)`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SONDA,lag(SONDA ignore nulls) over (order by ANSWER))
FROM TABLENAME;
```

OR Go with the simplest solution:

```
SELECT
t1.SURVEY_ID ,
CASE WHEN t1.SONDA IS NULL
THEN (SELECT top 1 t2.SONDA
FROM TABLE AS t2
WHERE t2.ANSWER< t1.ANSWER AND
t2.SONDA IS NOT NULL
)
ELSE t1.SONDA
END AS SONDA,
t1.ANSWER
FROM TABLE AS t1;
```

Comment: This assumes that the non-null `sonda` appears in the row with the lowest value of `answer`. That assumption may in fact be true, but it was not mentioned - it is just something you can see in the sample.

Comment: `TOP 1` is not valid Oracle syntax, you can change it to add an `ORDER BY` clause use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` and, in Oracle, you cannot have `AS` before a table alias. (But I'd also say that `LAG` is simpler and more performant than multiple self-joined sub-queries and you may want to add `PARTITION BY survey_id` to `LAG`).

Comment: Implementing those changes:  [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8617b8b83b8cb2eddfe0d80e630d82f7)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Huda Khan answer, given SONDA is not null on any row number (not just first row).

```
select 
(select sonda from test 
where sonda is not null fetch first 1 rows only) sonda 
from test 
connect by level=(select count(*) from test);
```

or - with CTE

```
with cte as
(select sonda from test 
where sonda is not null 
fetch first 1 rows only)
select cte.sonda from test,cte
```

Answer (score 0):

SAMPLE TABLE:

```
select * from test_table


SURVEY_ID    |  SONDA  | DATA_CRIA  | ANSWEAR
CHK-SON-CS-07   PR-05   06.04.2022    1
CHK-SON-CS-07           06.04.2022    2
CHK-SON-CS-07           06.04.2022    3
CHK-SON-CS-07           06.04.2022    4
CHK-SON-CS-07           06.04.2022    5
```

WITH THIS QUERY:

```
  select t1.survey_id, t2.sonda, t1.data_cria, t1.answer
  from test_table t1, 
  (select survey_id,sonda from test_table where sonda is not null) t2
  where t1.survey_id=t2.survey_id
```

RESULT:

```
SURVEY_ID    |  SONDA  | DATA_CRIA  | ANSWEAR
CHK-SON-CS-07   PR-05   06.04.2022    1
CHK-SON-CS-07   PR-05   06.04.2022    2
CHK-SON-CS-07   PR-05   06.04.2022    3
CHK-SON-CS-07   PR-05   06.04.2022    4
CHK-SON-CS-07   PR-05   06.04.2022    5
```